# PIC16F628 external timer1 interrupt

Tags: microchip

I'm having problems with timer1 external clock interrupts.
Basically I'm using internal 4mhz clock and a 32khz crystal generator connected to T1OSI/T1OSO pins.
The thing is that I'm unable to generate interrupt from external clock. Below is the code I'm trying to run:

```
 #define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSCIO  // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA7/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // RA5/MCLR/VPP Pin Function Select bit (RA5/MCLR/VPP pin function is digital input, MCLR internally tied to VDD)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Detect Enable bit (BOD disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage Programming Enable bit (RB4/PGM pin has digital I/O function, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EE Memory Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection off)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)
#include <xc.h>

void interrupt isr(void){
    if(TMR1IF){
        RA0=!RA0;
    }
}
void main(void) {
    CMCON = 0x07; // comparators off
    TRISA = 0x00;
    RA0=1;
    __delay_ms(1000);
    RA0=0;
    TMR1CS=1;
    T1CONbits.nT1SYNC = 0
    TMR1IF = 0;        // Clear the timer1 interrupt flag
    TMR1H  = 224;
    TMR1L  = 0;
    TMR1IE = 1;
    TMR1ON = 1;
    T1CKPS1 = 1;
    INTCON = 0b11000000;

  while(1);
}
```

This code works if using internal clock, but if configured to use external - it fails.
Maybe there's something I did wrong? Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: 1)Please mention micro-controller family like PIC18 PIC12 etc. 
2)I don't see any pin initialized for clock. PIC18F family requires the pin to be analog.

Comment: Hello, it's PIC16 (PIC16F628 to be more specific) (wrote that in subject)

Comment: Hi @Seitan I am sorry i missed that part! page 49 of the datasheet suggest the oscillator requirement. oscillators need spacial care in circuit.can you share the cap value and crystal part number?

Comment: Crystal resonator is standard clock crystal: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/3/ab38t-ab26t-180532.pdf  I've tried several options on capacitors: 15pf as stated in microchip manual. 22pf as shown in many electrical circuits. Result is the same - no interrupt is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some more tries, I've managed to got it working.
Using 33pf capacitors on 32khz external crystal.
Code:

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSCIO  // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA7/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // RA5/MCLR/VPP Pin Function Select bit (RA5/MCLR/VPP pin function is digital input, MCLR internally tied to VDD)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Detect Enable bit (BOD disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage Programming Enable bit (RB4/PGM pin has digital I/O function, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EE Memory Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection off)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

#include <xc.h>
void interrupt isr(void){
if(TMR1IF){
  TMR1ON = 0;
  RA0=~RA0;
  TMR1H = 0x80;
  TMR1L = 0x00;
  TMR1IF = 0;  
  TMR1ON = 1;
  }
}
void main(void) {
    CMCON = 0x07; // comparators off
    TRISA = 0x00;
    RA0=0;
    __delay_ms(5000);
    T1CKPS0 = 0;
    T1CKPS1 = 0;
    TMR1CS=1;
    TMR1H = 0x80;
    TMR1L = 0x00;
    T1OSCEN = 1;
    T1CONbits.nT1SYNC = 1;  
    TMR1IE = 1;
    GIE=1;
    PEIE=1; 
    TMR1ON = 1;
    while(1);
}
```

Now getting correct 1s pulses on RA0.
Basically it was badly configured pre-scaler and  counter register values.
Also you need to use TMR1ON after configuring timer.